# $file->eof() always returning false when using PHP's SplFileObject

Tags: php, fwrite, eof, splfileobject

Why is my PHP script hanging?

```
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '').'.txt';
$fileInfo = new \SplFileInfo($path);
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a');
$fileObject->fwrite("test line\n");
var_dump(file_exists($path));          // bool(true)
var_dump(file_get_contents($path));    // string(10) "test line
                                       // "
var_dump(iterator_count($fileObject)); // Hangs on this
```

If I delete the last line (`iterator_count(...`) and replace it with this:

```
$i = 0;
$fileObject->rewind();
while (!$fileObject->eof()) {
    var_dump($fileObject->eof());
    var_dump($i++);
    $fileObject->next();
}
// Output:
// bool(false)
// int(0)
// bool(false)
// int(1)
// bool(false)
// int(2)
// bool(false)
// int(3)
// bool(false)
// int(4)
// ...
```

The `$fileObject->eof()` always returns false so I get an infinite loop.

Why are these things happening? I need to get a line count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I see in your code, you are opening the file with mode `a` at this line:

```
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a');
```

When you do that, its write only:

`$fileObject->eof()` needs to read the file, you should open the file with `a+` to allow read/write:

```
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a+');
```

---

Ps: either with `a` or `a+`, the pointer goes to the end of the file.

Comment: It happens even if I create a second SplFileObject in 'r' mode. You've answered this one, thank you. I've created a new ticket for my real issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706174