# $file->eof() always returning false when using PHP's SplFileObject in 'r' mode

Tags: php, fwrite, eof, splfileobject

Why is my PHP script hanging?

```
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '').'.txt';
$fileInfo = new \SplFileInfo($path);
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a');
$fileObject->fwrite("test line\n");
$fileObject2 = $fileInfo->openFile('r');
var_dump(file_exists($path));          // bool(true)
var_dump(file_get_contents($path));    // string(10) "test line
                                       // "
var_dump(iterator_count($fileObject2)); // Hangs on this
```

If I delete the last line (`iterator_count(...`) and replace it with this:

```
$i = 0;
$fileObject2->rewind();
while (!$fileObject2->eof()) {
    var_dump($fileObject2->eof());
    var_dump($i++);
    $fileObject2->next();
}

// Output:
// bool(false)
// int(0)
// bool(false)
// int(1)
// bool(false)
// int(2)
// bool(false)
// int(3)
// bool(false)
// int(4)
// ...
```

The `$fileObject->eof()` always returns false so I get an infinite loop.

Why are these things happening? I need to get a line count.

Comment: "test line" is the only line @ your file?

Comment: @Zuul The code doesn't have any dependencies at all. You can run it as is. It creates a file in your temp directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why are these things happening?**

You are experiencing a peculiarity in the way that the `SplFileObject` class is written.  Without calling `next()` *and* `current()` methods—using the default (`0`) flags—the iterator never moves forward.

The `iterator_count()` function never calls `current()`; it checks `valid()` and calls `next()` only.  Your bespoke loops only call one or other of `current()` and `next()`.

This should be considered a bug (whether in PHP itself, or a failure in the documentation) and the following code *should* (and does not) work as expected.  I invite you to [report this misbehaviour](https://bugs.php.net).

```
// NOTE: This currently runs in an infinite loop!
$file = new SplFileObject(__FILE__);
var_dump(iterator_count($file));
```

**Workarounds**

One quick sidestep to get things moving is to set the `READ_AHEAD` flag on the object.  This will cause the `next()` method to read the next available line.

```
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
```

If, for any reason, you do not want the *read ahead* behaviour then you must call both `next()` and `current()` yourself.

**Back to the original problem of two SplFileObjects**

The following should now work as you expected, allowing appending to a file and reading its line count.

```
<?php
$info = new SplFileInfo(__FILE__);
$write = $info->openFile('a');
$write->fwrite("// new line\n");
$read = $info->openFile('r');
$read->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
var_dump(iterator_count($read));
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDITED 01

If what you need is the number of lines inside the file:

```
<?php

$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '').'.txt';

$fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($path);
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a+');

$fileObject->fwrite("Foo".PHP_EOL);
$fileObject->fwrite("Bar".PHP_EOL);

echo count(file($path));  // outputs 2

?>
```

---

### EDITED 02

This is your code above, but without entering into infinite loops due to the file pointer:

```
<?php

$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '').'.txt';

$fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($path);
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a+');

$fileObject->fwrite("Foo".PHP_EOL);
$fileObject->fwrite("Bar");

foreach($fileObject as $line_num => $line) {
    echo 'Line: '.$line_num.' "'.$line.'"'."<br/>";
}
echo 'Total Lines:' . $fileObject->key();

?>
```

**Outputs**

> Line: 0 "Foo "
>
> Line: 1 "Bar"
>
> Total Lines:2

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The logic applied was a bit off. I simplified the code:

```
<?php

// set path to tmp with random file name
echo $path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '').'.txt';
echo "<br/>";

// new object
$fileInfo = new \SplFileInfo($path);

// open to write
$fileObject = $fileInfo->openFile('a');

// write two lines
$fileObject->fwrite("Foo".PHP_EOL);
$fileObject->fwrite("Bar".PHP_EOL);

// open to read
$fileObject2 = $fileInfo->openFile('r');

// output contents
echo "File Exists: " .file_exists($path);
echo "<br/>";
echo "File Contents: " . file_get_contents($path);
echo "<br/>";

// foreach line get line number and line contents 
foreach($fileObject2 as $line_num => $line) {
  echo 'Line: '.$line_num;
  echo ' With: "'.$line.'" is the end? '.($fileObject2->eof()?'yes':'no')."<br>";
}

?>
```

**Outputs:**

> /tmp/EAdklY.txt
>
> File Exists: 1
>
> File Contents: Foo Bar
>
> Line: 0 With: "Foo " is the end? no
>
> Line: 1 With: "Bar " is the end? no
>
> Line: 2 With: "" is the end? yes

Comment: Using foreach is a workaround (that I'm using until I figure out the real problem). +1

Answer (score 0):

While it may seem counter intuitive, with PHP 5.3.9, this:

```
<?php
$f = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'r');
while (!$f->eof()) {
    $f->next();
}
```

while be an infinite loop, and never exit.

The following will exit, when the end of the file is reached:

```
<?php
$f = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'r');
while (!$f->eof()) {
    $f->current();
}
```

So:

```
$i = 0;
$fileObject2->rewind();
while (!$fileObject2->eof()) {
    var_dump($fileObject2->eof());
    var_dump($i++);
    $fileObject2->next();
}
```

should be rewritten as:

```
$fileObject2->rewind();
while (!$fileObject2->eof()) {
    $fileObject2->current();
}

$i = $fileObject2->key();
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the `var_dump(iterator_count($fileObject2));` line hang though?

Comment: Upon testing, it still hangs, even when I substitute `next` with `current`.

Comment: *what* still hangs? The `iterator_count()` call? It doesn't appear you can use this function on `SPLFileObject` objects. It appears you will need to iterator the object yourself.

Comment: The `eof` method still returns false, every time.

Comment: The above example clearly shows the `eof()` function *does* return false, when you use the `current()` function. That indicates you have a different, and not one with `eof()`.